# Does Enlarge/Reduce affect Stone golems?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, immunities

Does the *Enlarge/Reduce* spell affect the Stone Golem? I had a player try to cast it on one, but I countered it because of the immutable form ability saying that counts as trying to change the form.

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [*Enlarge/Reduce*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) does not affect the stone golem.

[*Enlarge/Reduce*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) (PHB 237) is a transmutation spell that changes (alters) the properties of a target creature, the target creature Stone Golem (MM 167, MM 170) is immune to that effect.

***Immutable Form*** (MM 170) prevents the alteration

> ***Immutable Form***. The golem is immune to any spell or effect that would alter its form.

caused by the transmutation spell (PHB 203):

> **Transmutation** spells change the properties of a creature,
>   object, or environment.

Analytical:
All transmutation spells alter the properties of the affected entity. Enlarge/Reduce is a transmutation spell. Enlarge/Reduce changes, among other effects, the size and weight. Changes of size and weight are changes of the original form. These changes of size and weight are alterations of form caused by a spell. The Stone golem is immune to alterations effects and spells that change their form. The Stone Golem is immune to the spell Enlarge/Reduce.

Comment: I think your definition of form is inappropriately broad. When D&D doesn't specifically define a term you use the dictionary definition, according to Merriam-Webster Form is : the shape and structure of something as distinguished from its material //the building's massive form. In the example sentence the definition distinguishes size from form and all of the synonyms are somehow related to shape and never size. It really is arguable that size is independent of form by English definition. And size is arguably a different property than shape or form that can be changed by transmutation spells.

Comment: @duck may I suggest you make a case for your opinion in an answer and let the votes decide who is more right?

Comment: @ryan are you asking for their opinion, or did you infer that from their answer? Because nothing in this answer suggests that a golem is immune to all transmutation spells, in my opinion.

Comment: @Duck appearance is included in that same definition, including spatial relations. The definition is very broad. Including in original form and condition of existance. If you want to argue based on that definition, then it can get even broader than what I use here.

Comment: @Akixkisu Sure, but you could even just skip the first 2 sentences entirely and the argument would still be equally valid. You might also want to address whether or not the other non-form-changing effects of the spell still work (e.g. advantage on STR checks and extra damage for enlarge).

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson no, that would be unnecessarily obtuse, the reader should be able to understand that immune to a spell means immune to its effects.